# Can't use responsive to datatable

Tags: html, css, datatable

I've added `responsive: true` but my table won't collapse. Also tried adding this to the css:

```
body {
 table-layout: fixed
}
```

But still won't work. Any solutions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] for guidance on how you can improve your question.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide a [mre] - otherwise, we can only guess what the problem may be. Here is my guess: Make sure you have included the additional [responsive resources](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) (JS and CSS) needed for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add the following stylesheet:
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.9/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css